# hibernate validator 4.2.0 Final @CreditCardNumber

Tags: unit-testing, validation, credit-card, hibernate-validator

```
@Autowired
private Validator validator;

    @Test
        public void testValidateMethodOfPaymentBadCreditCard() {
            final MethodOfPayment mop = new MethodOfPayment();
            command.setDescription("1234567890");
            final Set<ConstraintViolation<MethodOfPayment>> constraintViolations = this.validator.validateProperty(mop, "cardNumber", Default.class);
            Assert.assertFalse(constraintViolations.isEmpty());
            for (final ConstraintViolation<MethodOfPayment> cv : constraintViolations) {
                Assert.assertEquals(cv.getMessage(), "{error.invalid.cardNumber}");
            }
        }
```

The unit class has instance of define in my xml.

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

my methodofpayment is annotated with

```
@CreditCardNumber(message="{error.invalid.cardNumber}")
    public String getCardNumber() {
        return this.cardNumber;
    }
```

This test fails on line saying the constraint violation is empty. I thought it should not be empty right?

What is wrong? 
What kind of data fails for credit card validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`null` is considered as valid value for most constraints defined in Bean Validation and Hibernate Validator.

Hence you won't get a constraint violation if you don't assign a value to the `cardNumber` property or annotate it with `@NotNull` (btw. your listing seems a bit strange, where does `command` come from?)

The validator for `@CreditCardNumber` uses the [Luhn algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) for checking credit card numbers.

Comment: Hi the command should be mop.setDescription. Yeah thanks for pointing out error. I was setting description not the card number, thus it was never validated.